# Function not getting called in Mocha test

Tags: javascript, express, mocha.js

I am working on an Express.js app. The current feature is creating an appointment with a post request and getting and saving data from third party API, then sending updated API data in the subsequent request. The feature is fully working but in the test, the function to get API data is not getting called.

Route to create appointment:

```
app.post('/schedule', requestHandler.postSchedule);
```

The request handler for creating appointment:

```
requestHandler.postSchedule = function (req, res) {
  let appointment = {
    // posted data
  };

  new Appointment(appointment)
    .save()
    .then(newAppointment => {
      if(req.body.cityName && req.body.cityName !== '') {
        console.log('req.body.cityName', req.body.cityName);
        weatherHelper.addNewCityWeatherData(req.body.cityName);
      }
      return newAppointment;
    })
    .then(newAppointment => {
      // do some other stuff
      res.send(newAppointment);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      error(err);
    });
};
```

Function to add weather data:

```
exports.addNewCityWeatherData = (city) => {
  console.log('City in addNewCityWeatherData', city);
  getCurrentTrackingCities(cities => {
    if(cities.indexOf(city) < 0) {
      console.log(city + ' data not in weather');
      getWeatherData(city, data => {
        console.log('Got weather data');
        addWeatherDataToDB(city, data);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('City exists');
    }
  });
};
```

Function to get weather data from API:

```
getWeatherData = (city, callback) => {
  console.log('getWeatherData called', city);
  let url = `http://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.json?key=${weatherApiKey}&q=${city}&days=${10}`
  request(url, (err, res, body) => {
    console.log('Weather data received body');
    callback(body);
  });
};
```

When testing, this feature fails and all console logs are printed except the 'Weather data received body' and the logs in consequent functions.

Here is my test:

```
describe.only('Weather data', function() {
  let requestWithSession = request.defaults({jar: true});

  let hashedPass = bcrypt.hashSync('testpass', null);

  beforeEach((done) => {
    new User({
      'name': 'Test User',
      'email': 'testuser@test.com',
      'password': hashedPass
    })
    .save()
    .then(() => {
      let options = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'uri': testHost + '/login',
        'form': {
          'email': 'testuser@test.com',
          'password': 'testpass'
        }
      };
      requestWithSession(options, (err, res, body) => {
        done();
      });
    });
  }); // beforeEach

  afterEach((done) => {
    // remove test stuff from db
  }); // afterEach

  it('Adds weather data when an appointment with new city is posted', (done) => {
    let options = {
      'method': 'POST',
      'uri': testHost + '/schedule',
      'form': {
        'title': 'Test title',
        'description': 'Test description',
        'start_date_time': '2017-07-19 01:00',
        'end_date_time': '2017-07-19 02:00',
        'cityName': 'New York',
        'isTrackingWeather': 'true'
      }
    };

    // post request to add appointment data
    requestWithSession(options, (err, res, body) => {
      if(err) {
        console.log('DatabaseError in Weather Data');
        throw {
          type: 'DatabaseError',
          message: 'Failed to create test setup data'
        };
      }

      let options = {
        'method': 'GET',
        'uri': testHost + '/allweather'
      };

      // subsequesnt request to get updated weather data
      requestWithSession(options, (err, res, body) => {
        let found = false;
        weatherData = JSON.parse(body);
        // console.log('weatherData in test', weatherData);
        weatherData.forEach(weather => {
          if(weather.location && weather.location.name === 'New York') {
            found = true;
          }
        });
        expect(found).to.be.true;
        done();
      });

    });
  });
}); // Weather Data
```

Here is the terminal output:

[image: Mocha test]

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run your test is that the test suite make a request to your test server, and the code that handles the request in your test server makes *another* request to another host.

You do not get to see `'Weather data received body'` because the request handled by your test server is not *waiting* for the request that the test server itself makes. `addNewCityWeatherData` has no callback and does not return a promise, so the code that calls it goes on its merry way without waiting for it to complete. You should modify it to allow for the calling code to wait for a result.

Also, I'm not seeing how the data from the request initiated by your test server is folded back into the request that comes from your test suite. You may have to add some code for that too, unless `addWeatherDataToDB(city, data);` is taking care of it automatically somehow.